# Find all partial derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, multivalued-functions

We have a funcion of 2 variables $z = g(x,y)$. And $x = cos(t)$,$y = sin(t)$. Find all partial derivatives

is it right that
$$\frac{∂z}{∂x}=\frac{∂}{∂x}g(x,y)*(x)'_x=\frac{∂}{∂x}g(x,y)$$
$$\frac{∂z}{∂y}=\frac{∂}{∂y}g(x,y)_y*(y)'_y=\frac{∂}{∂y}g(x,y)$$
$$\frac{∂z}{∂t}=\frac{∂z}{∂x}\frac{∂x}{∂t} + \frac{∂z}{∂y}\frac{∂y}{∂t} = \frac{∂}{∂x}g(x,y)*(-sin(t)) + \frac{∂}{∂y}g(x,y)*cos(t)$$

Comment: Nobody uses the notation $g'(x,y)_x$, write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}g(x,y)$, because this is what it is, the partial derivative in $x$ direction. And for $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} z$ you need to use the chain rule to obtain $\frac{\partial }{\partial t} z = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$.

Comment: @stange, Thank you!